# Changing values of element of NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I've got a NSMutableArray with NSMutableArrays as elements like

```
[dataBase insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@(100), @"3379429411", @"Cont10", @(0), @(0), @(0), @(0),@"Name1",@"Name2",@"Name3",@"Name4",@"192.168.0.1",@(0),@(0),@(0),@(0), nil] atIndex: 0];
```

I often need to find an element which second member equals to another integer and to change different values of this array.

I use standard operations like `for(int n = 0; n < [dataBase count]; n++)` and then I create temporary array and then `[dataBase replaceObjectAtIndex:n withObject:tempArray];`

Is there any better way?

Comment: If you're replacing NSMutableArray objects in dataBase then they don't need to be mutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are talking about, try this:

Rather than use an array of arrays, why not use a dictionary of array and use the second member element of the array as the dictionary key. So something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dataBase = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *firstRow = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@(100), @"3379429411", @"Cont10", @(0), @(0), @(0), @(0),@"Name1",@"Name2",@"Name3",@"Name4",@"192.168.0.1",@(0),@(0),@(0),@(0), nil] atIndex: 0];
dataBase[firstRow[1]] = firstRow;
```

That way when you need to replace a row all you have to do is:

```
NSMutableArray *newRow = [self getNewRow];
dataBase[newRow[1]] = newRow;
```